# Convert EBCDIC to UTF8 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert an ebcdic string to a utf8 string. I use the below online tool to test this, which is very good, for conversion related stuffs.

http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php

I want to convert `£ˆ‰¢‰¢¤£†ø` which is in EBCDIC to UTF8 string, which is `thisisutf8` You can use the above link to test.

I refered the below article on how to read EBCDIC data in .net

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/EasyEbcdicToAscii.aspx

Then I used the same method to read the ebcdic data

```
Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = _
                    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(37)
```

However I am not getting the expected data

Here is my code, to get the result into a atring, a.

```
Dim a As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(37).GetBytes("£ˆ‰¢‰¢¤£†ø"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to convert £ˆ‰¢‰¢¤£†ø

That's too late, looks like you already converted it to a string.  You'll need to read bytes instead.  Then use Encoding.GetString() to convert the ebcdic encoded bytes to a .NET string.  Then use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() to convert that back to bytes.

Alternatively, and more practically, use the StreamReader(string, Encoding) overload to open the ebcdic file, passing the ebcdic Encoding.  And StreamWriter(string) to write it back, it already defaults to utf-8.